# Set And Verify Sized Collection Item in Solana Rust

Tags: rust, mpl-token-metadata

I am trying to use the SetAndVerifySizedCollectionItem instruction for verifying a collection item. However, I am encountering an error that seems to arise from a mismatch in the expected account type. The instruction seems to expect a MasterEdition2 account, but in my implementation, I am using MasterEditionV3.

Is the SetAndVerifySizedCollectionItem instruction compatible with MasterEditionV3, or does it specifically require MasterEdition2?

I am using this [rust cargo](https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/instructions/index.html) - the latest one, which does not have any instruction for MasterEditionV2.

Here is error details

```
Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3f", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(63))), logs: Some(["Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]", "Program log: IX: Set and Verify Collection", "Program log: Data type mismatch", "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 10245 of 200000 compute units", "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x3f"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you're getting is unfortunately a bit vague: `Data type mismatch`: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/64ba3cb8937dff668a5e1926d3beaf694ea6f3dc/programs/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L268C5-L268C21

There is no master edition v3, but there is a v3 of the create master edition instruction, which is the source of the confusion. Your v2 master edition should work.

Without seeing your code, you might need to flip around some parameters into the instruction, or one of the accounts isn't properly initialized. Be sure to go through every account and make sure that it matches in the instruction. In your case, that means for https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/instructions/struct.SetAndVerifySizedCollectionItem.html, you need:

```
pub struct SetAndVerifySizedCollectionItem {
    pub metadata: Pubkey,
    pub collection_authority: Pubkey,
    pub payer: Pubkey,
    pub update_authority: Pubkey,
    pub collection_mint: Pubkey,
    pub collection: Pubkey,
    pub collection_master_edition_account: Pubkey,
    pub collection_authority_record: Option<Pubkey>,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I was baffled by the terms... Based on your shared structure, I double-checked my input params and fixed the issue!